# Masking the printed String in C

Tags: c, string

Is it possible to mask a string only by using printf function?

There's static string stored in a char array. The user will enter a number which is the number of characters that the user wants to be printed. Supposing the string is 14 characters and the user enters 20, is it possible to mask the string so it replaces the last 6 chars with '*' only by using printf function?

Comment: No, but 2-3 lines of code do the job.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @4386427 not good enough

Comment: How big is the char array?  If is too small to replaces the last N chars with '*' , the problem now becomes a space management one too.  Add more detail for clarity.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - well, it is for you to decide. I just think that the answer no with a 2-3 line alternative would be a great answer :-)

Comment: Let me explain more. Suppose the string which will be printed is "This is a sample string in c." which is 29 characters. If the user enters 29 the whole string would be printed. If the user enters a number less than this, a shorter string will be printed (which could be done by using %ns replacing n with the number the user entered) but I don't know if it is possible that only by using printf format specifiers, when the user enters a number greater than 29, the extra characters would be replaced with '*'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were content with spaces rather than wanting asterisks, then you could do it straight-forwardly.

Since you require asterisks, the answer is 'not really' — at least, not if the amount of padding needed can be arbitrarily large.  If the amount of padding will never be more than N bytes, you can create a string of N asterisks and work around it.

Your question doesn't specify what should happen if the source string is longer than the N specified by the user.  This implementation assumes that the first N characters of the string should be printed with no masking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* For inclusion in a header file */
extern void mask_string(const char *str, int n, char pad);

static inline int min(int x, int y) { return (x < y) ? x : y; }
static inline int max(int x, int y) { return (x > y) ? x : y; }

void mask_string(const char *str, int n, char pad)
{
    char buffer[n+1];
    memset(buffer, pad, n);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    int len1 = min(strlen(str), n);
    int len2 = max(n - (int)strlen(str), 0);
    printf("%.*s%.*s", len1, str, len2, buffer);
}

/* Test code */

static void test_mask_string(const char *data, int i)
{
    printf("%2d: [", i);
    mask_string(data, i, '*');
    putchar(']');
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    char data[] = "suppose the string";
    for (int i = 11; i < 24; i++)
        test_mask_string(data, i);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample output

Tested on macOS Sierra 10.12.3 with GCC 6.2.0.

```
11: [suppose the]
12: [suppose the ]
13: [suppose the s]
14: [suppose the st]
15: [suppose the str]
16: [suppose the stri]
17: [suppose the strin]
18: [suppose the string]
19: [suppose the string*]
20: [suppose the string**]
21: [suppose the string***]
22: [suppose the string****]
23: [suppose the string*****]
```

#### Using just `printf()`

The code shown has 5 lines of code plus the two inline (one-line) functions.  I'd rather not eliminate the functions, but as long as you always want asterisks and never more than (say) 80 of them, then you could reduce that to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* For inclusion in a header file */
extern void mask_string(const char *str, int n);

static inline int min(int x, int y) { return (x < y) ? x : y; }
static inline int max(int x, int y) { return (x > y) ? x : y; }

void mask_string(const char *str, int n)
{
    printf("%.*s%.*s", min(strlen(str), n), str,
                       max(n - (int)strlen(str), 0),
                       "****************************************"
                       "****************************************");
}

/* Test code */

static void test_mask_string(const char *data, int i)
{
    printf("%2d: [", i);
    mask_string(data, i);
    putchar(']');
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    char data[] = "suppose the string";
    for (int i = 11; i < 24; i++)
        test_mask_string(data, i);
    return 0;
}
```

The test output from this is the same as before.

Note the use of string literal concatenation.  If I were going this route, I'd be tempted to add an assertion to ensure that the code wasn't requesting too many asterisks:

```
assert(max(n - strlen(str), 0) <= 80);
```

or even to use a a macro:

```
#define STARS "****************************************" \
              "****************************************"
```

and:

```
assert(max(n - strlen(str), 0) < sizeof(STARS));
printf("%.*s%.*s", min(strlen(str), n), str,
                   max(n - strlen(str), 0), STARS);
```

Clearly, if you insist on not using the inline functions, you can write them out in the argument list to `printf()`.  I don't think it will make the code clearer.